# Recommendations for black and white color scheme with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to produce many diagrams structured like this:

[image]

Is there an easy of producing something that looks good in black and white? I did read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2) but it still is producing a colored fill.

Comment: Also, [**beanplots!!!**](http://jnlnet.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/beanplots/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I am not sure if color really helps in this graph, since it is already clear what each boxplot corresponds to. However, if you still need to color this in black and white, you can achieve it using `scale_fill_grey`. Here is an example

```
library(ggplot2)
data(tips)
p0 = qplot(day, tip/total_bill, data = tips, geom = 'boxplot', fill = day) + 
  scale_fill_grey()
print(p0)
```

This produces the output shown below
[image]

Comment: You may want to use theme_bw() in this case as well, to bring out the gray contrast a bit better. Also, check out ?scale_colour_brewer() for colour palettes that will degrade gracefully in B&W.  And don't forget to reorder your factor into an order that makes sense ...

Comment: What I meant about colorBrewer is in the answer to the question referred to above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2/3011030#3011030 . It will produce colour fills, but ones that should robust to translation to grayscale.

Comment: Thanks - part of my reason for using color, is that it is shown with a related map. The b/w colors you describe should do the job!

Answer (score 9):

The default `fill` colour for ggplot is black and white:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price, group=cut)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

If you prefer not to have the greyscale panel, you can use the black and white theme:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price, group=cut)) + geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

To get a colour or greyscale `fill` as a scale you have to add fill as a parameter to `aes` (as illustrated by @ramnath).