# In ggplot2 theme_bw() doesn't draw back grid lines anymore

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Context**: R/ggplot2.

If I am not mistaken, theme_bw() used to draw some black gridlines, but with the latest version it doesn't. Is there a way to restore previous situation ?

Comment: By 'latest' you mean the current CRAN version or the development one?

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981601/recommendations-for-black-and-white-color-scheme-with-ggplot2) relatively old question, the grid there is grey, which is also confirmed by the theme definition [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/themes). So I suppose it has always been the same.

To "restore" black grid lines, use

```
qplot(1:10) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.2))
```