# Pattern fills for graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

As `ggplot2` produces nice colored graphs but sometimes it is required to have black and white graphs with [pattern fills](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2007/11/16/chart-pattern-fills.aspx). I wonder how to do this in `ggplot2`, say for this code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
```

**Edit**

Is there any function in `R` to do pattern fills for graphs?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg74619.html) and quite a few other results that note that grid doesn't support patterned fills of polygons.

Comment: Any other R function having pattern fills capabilities?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. If you're looking into this because the graph will be printed in black and white, consider simply using a greyscale color palette.

Comment: a proof-of-concept for grid rectangles is in `gridExtra`, `example(patternGrob)`. Not that I'd recommend it though.

Comment: the `gridSVG` package seems to be fairly close to providing a solution using `grid.garnish()` and fills defined as in this page http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html

Comment: I've added an answer in the following thread that provides a few approaches to adding pattern fills: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20426482/2653210

Answer (score 3):

have a look at the 6th plot of example(barplot).

Comment: it involves setting the `angle` and `density` parameters