# Can you add texture to a box plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a command to add a pattern or texture to the fill of boxplots?  I have my variables colour coded, but I want them to also be distinguishable in greyscale...

Many thanks!

Comment: I suppose I was wondering if there had been an update since 2011...

Answer (score 0):

As Hadley commented in a previous string. It is currently not possible.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901210/2762612