# How to differentiate Bars in geom_bar without color: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

### Note: A similar question is present at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2895319/3317829), but I posed it a separate question due to: 1) only a hack is provided to the previos question which I thought would make code unnecessary complex 2) I thought after 2013 a fix might have been suggested for this

I am using following code to draw bars/stacks

```
  ggplot(finaldataframe,aes(day,score))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=identify),stat="identity",position = "dodge",width = .7, show.legend = TRUE)+
    labs(x= "Day of the Month", y="Anomaly Score") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Method", labels=c("Mean","Maximum","Cumulative \n sum"))+
  theme(axis.text= element_text(color="Black"))+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,31,5))
```

A portion of output is as

[image]

The problem with this figure is that once I print this via black and white printer It gets hard to differentiate between different stacks. Is there any way to make the stacks differentiable on a black and white print. I am looking for some what like this:

[image]

For reproduction, Here is the dput of dataframe:

```
> dput(finaldataframe)
finaldataframe = structure(list(day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L), score = c(0, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.28, 0.24, 0.01, 0.94, 0.22, 0.25, 0.01, 0.31, 0.22, 
0.24, 0.83, 0.4, 0.44, 0.06, 0.02, 0.37, 0.07, 0.12, 0.06, 0.1, 
0.06, 0.1, 0, 0.05, 0.04, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 
0.37, 0.36, 0.04, 1, 0.28, 0.34, 0.03, 0.55, 0.35, 0.32, 1, 0.71, 
1, 0.13, 0.04, 0.47, 0.12, 0.17, 0.1, 0.18, 0.1, 0.14, 0, 0.02, 
0.01, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.3, 0.25, 0.01, 1, 0.23, 
0.27, 0, 0.33, 0.24, 0.26, 0.89, 0.42, 0.47, 0.06, 0.02, 0.4, 
0.07, 0.13, 0.06, 0.11, 0.06, 0.1), identify = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Mean", 
"Maximum", "Cummulative Sum"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("day", 
"score", "identify"), row.names = c(NA, 93L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How about `alpha = identify` instead of `fill = identify`?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2

Comment: @KotaMori, yes alpha makes some sense, but still one bar gets un- differentiable from background colour

Comment: You can put a black border around all bars, negating that issue.

Comment: `+ theme_bw()` makes the background white.  Also, `+ scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1))` specifies the range of grey scales.  Is either of these work for you?

Comment: Also, check out "photocopy friendly" palettes at http://colorbrewer2.org/