# Planned contrasts using ezANOVA output in R

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

I've been looking into using planned contrasts as opposed to post-hoc t-tests. I typically use `ezANOVA` (Type III ANOVA) but it seems that conducting planned contrasts using `ezANOVA` is not currently catered for.

`aov()` on the other hand is a Type I ANOVA (I don't want to get into a debate about which type is best for which type of design). It is straight forward to conduct planned contrasts using `aov()` (for between group designs) but I want to conduct a Type III ANOVA in a repeated measures and to be frank `ezANOVA` has a much more user friendly output.

Bearing in mind `ezANOVA` has the option to include `return_aov = TRUE` does anyone know of a way to use the information provided by `ezANOVA` to conduct planned contrasts?

**Note:** `return_aov = TRUE` allows access to the output of `aov` via something along these lines:

```
summary.lm(ModelName$aov$'Participant:IndependentVariable1')
```

Participant above is an example variable added to `wid` in `ezANOVA`:

```
wid = .(Participant)
```

`summary.lm()` is typically used when presenting the results of planned contrasts in `aov`, granted between groups ANOVAs as opposed to repeated measures.

I'm particularly interested in using the output to conduct planned contrasts for repeated measures ANOVA.

**BOUNTY GOALS**

Goals I would like to achieve from this bounty:

1) Use the output of `ezANOVA` to conduct planned contrasts in a repeated measures ANOVA.

1A) Use the output of `ezANOVA` to conduct planned contrasts on between subjects ANOVA (this one should be relatively easy & therefore not a requisite to claim the bounty.)

Any dummy data should suffice but here is a reminder of the format for `ezANOVA` repeated measures ANOVA:

```
ModelName <- ezANOVA(
data = DataSet,
dv = .(DependentVariable), 
wid = .(Participant), 
within = .(IndependentVariable1, IndependentVariable2), 
type=3, 
detailed = TRUE, 
return_aov = TRUE)
```

This is a [Related Question with reproducible data and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933702/summary-lm-output-when-using-aov-in-r) which can be used in relation to this problem.

You can find a [PDF here giving some background on planned contrasts](http://www.upa.pdx.edu/IOA/newsom/da1/ho_planned%20contrasts.pdf) and what they do.

Comment: According to a statement by the package developer made in 2012 or so, there is no way of using `ez` for planned contrasts. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ez4r/RpwYT6pEva0 . However, if you follow this link, alternatives are being discussed that might be helpful. It might also be useful to see if he has updated something since then...

Comment: @coffeinjunky I suspect that the author is referring to a lack of direct functionality written in ezANOVA but it *may* be possible to use the information it produces to work with a new function. For example, I provided a 'hack' for ggplot 2 using the available functionality in a way it was not intended here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20426482/2653210 This is what I'm hoping this bounty will encourage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `emmeans` package provides the appropriate functionality to calculate custom contrasts/arbitrary linear functions of the estimates marginal means (EMMs) for `aov` and `aovlist` objects (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html) for a full list of supported models).

In the following I use the `ANT` data set which comes with the `ez` package.

First we set up a mixed factorial ANOVA using `ezANOVA`. Note that one needs to set orthogonal contrasts in order to get meaningful Type-III tests (see, e.g., John Fox' answer [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-August/111854.html)).

```
library("ez")
library("emmeans")

# set orthogonal contrasts
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))

data(ANT)
rt_anova <- ezANOVA(data = ANT[ANT$error == 0, ], 
                    dv = rt,
                    wid = subnum, 
                    within = .(cue, flank),
                    between = group,
                    type = 3,
                    return_aov = TRUE)
```

We can then calculate the EMMs for, say all group-flank combinations.

```
emm <- emmeans(rt_anova$aov, ~ group * flank)
emm
## group     flank         emmean       SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
## Control   Neutral     381.5546 1.735392 53.97 378.0753 385.0339
## Treatment Neutral     379.9286 1.735392 53.97 376.4493 383.4079
## Control   Congruent   381.6363 1.735392 53.97 378.1570 385.1155
## Treatment Congruent   379.7520 1.735392 53.97 376.2727 383.2313
## Control   Incongruent 466.6770 1.735392 53.97 463.1977 470.1563
## Treatment Incongruent 452.2352 1.735392 53.97 448.7559 455.7145
```

Now it is easy to calculate all pairwise comparisons or any desired contrast on these EMMs.
See also [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter13.pdf) book chapter and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54015241/8905144) if you need a bit more detail on how one can derive the contrasts weights from the hypotheses.

```
# all pairwise comparisons 
pairs(emm, adjust = "Holm")
## contrast                                        estimate       SE    df t.ratio p.value
## Control,Neutral - Treatment,Neutral           1.62594836 2.454215 53.97   0.663  1.0000
## Control,Neutral - Control,Congruent          -0.08167403 2.473955 36.00  -0.033  1.0000
## Control,Neutral - Treatment,Congruent         1.80259257 2.454215 53.97   0.734  1.0000
## Control,Neutral - Control,Incongruent       -85.12239797 2.473955 36.00 -34.407  <.0001
## Control,Neutral - Treatment,Incongruent     -70.68062093 2.454215 53.97 -28.800  <.0001
## Treatment,Neutral - Control,Congruent        -1.70762239 2.454215 53.97  -0.696  1.0000
## Treatment,Neutral - Treatment,Congruent       0.17664421 2.473955 36.00   0.071  1.0000
## Treatment,Neutral - Control,Incongruent     -86.74834633 2.454215 53.97 -35.347  <.0001
## Treatment,Neutral - Treatment,Incongruent   -72.30656929 2.473955 36.00 -29.227  <.0001
## Control,Congruent - Treatment,Congruent       1.88426660 2.454215 53.97   0.768  1.0000
## Control,Congruent - Control,Incongruent     -85.04072394 2.473955 36.00 -34.374  <.0001
## Control,Congruent - Treatment,Incongruent   -70.59894690 2.454215 53.97 -28.766  <.0001
## Treatment,Congruent - Control,Incongruent   -86.92499054 2.454215 53.97 -35.419  <.0001
## Treatment,Congruent - Treatment,Incongruent -72.48321351 2.473955 36.00 -29.299  <.0001
## Control,Incongruent - Treatment,Incongruent  14.44177704 2.454215 53.97   5.884  <.0001
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: cue 
## P value adjustment: holm method for 15 tests 

# custom contrasts
contrast(
  emm, 
  list(c1 = c(1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0), # reproduces first pairwise comparison
       # emmean of row 1 - (emmean of row 1 + emmean of row 2) / 2; see EMMs table
       # 381.5546 - (379.9286 + 381.6363) / 2
       c2 = c(1, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 0))
 )
 ## contrast  estimate       SE    df t.ratio p.value
 ## c1       1.6259484 2.454215 53.97   0.663  0.5105
 ## c2       0.7721372 2.136825 43.84   0.361  0.7196
```

The same applies for purely within-subjects ANOVAs or between-subjects ANOVAs.

```
# within-subjects ANOVA
rt_anova_wi <- ezANOVA(data = ANT[ANT$error == 0, ], 
                    dv = rt,
                    wid = subnum, 
                    within = .(cue, flank),
                    type = 3,
                    return_aov = TRUE)

emm <- emmeans(rt_anova_wi$aov, ~ cue * flank)
contrast(
  emm, 
  list(c1 = c(1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
       c2 = c(1, -0.5, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
) 
## contrast estimate       SE     df t.ratio p.value
## c1       47.31005 3.802857 170.34  12.441  <.0001
## c2       50.35320 3.293371 170.34  15.289  <.0001

# between-subjects ANOVA
rt_anova_bw <- ezANOVA(data = ANT[ANT$error == 0, ], 
                       dv = rt,
                       wid = subnum, 
                       within_full = .(cue, flank), 
                       between = group,
                       type = 3,
                       return_aov = TRUE)

emm_bw <- emmeans(rt_anova_bw$aov, ~ group)
# custom linear function
contrast(
  emm_bw, 
  list(c1 = c(2/3, 1/2)) 
)
## contrast estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
## c1       475.2899 0.8213448 18 578.673  <.0001
```