# R-stacked-grouped barplot with different fill in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I have the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

K  <- data.frame(KK=c("30", "30", "30", "30","10", "10", "10", "10"),k=c("10", "8", "5", "2","10", "8", "5", "2"), 
               Precision=c(85.2,87.5,100,100,82.5,83.3,85.2,94.4),     
               Recall=c(73.3,80,100,100,51.4,54.8,61.1,87.9) , 
               Fscore=c(70.8,79.4,100,100,49.1,54.2,62.7,90.3),
               Accuracy=c(82.2,86.7,100,100,63.3,66.7,73.3,93.3)) 
  df2 <- reshape2::melt(K, 1:2)

   ggplot(df2, 
   aes(k, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
 theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

This code gives me the following plot. [image]

However, I want to get a barplot like this

[image]

Each value of k (10,8,5,2) should be a group of bars and each colour of bar a metric. In addition, the bar from the KK value 30 should be solid and with KK of 10 stripped. I don't know if it is clear. In my output appears the values for K30, but missing with K10 merged with K30 stripped.

Comment: a first step is to work with `dodge` instead of `stack`:

`geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')`

Comment: Thank you kbrunner, I just updated it.

Comment: Maybe you should create a new variable with the difference of, e.g. Precision 1 und Precision 2 at k= 10, and then stack them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply add the two different layers to your plot one for each `KK` value. Unfortunately, `ggplot` does not handle patterns well (or at all really), see this post: [How to add texture to fill colors in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2/2901210#2901210)

The code to add different layers for each `KK` value is:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=df2[which(df2$KK==10),], aes(k, value, fill = variable),stat = 'identity',position="dodge") +
  geom_bar(data=df2[which(df2$KK==30),], aes(k, value, fill = variable),stat = 'identity',position="dodge",alpha=0.5) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

[image]

Comment: how can I add the values for each bar (and type) at the top? I've tried with geom_text(aes(df2$k,df2$variable,label=df2$value),position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=0.9) but appears the following error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". How can I solve this?

Comment: You're trying to pass `df2$variable` as a y-value, but your y-axis is already continuous (its based on `df2$value`. To not get an error this works: `geom_text(aes(df2$k,df2$value,label=df2$value),position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=0.9)`. However, this wont give the correct horizontal position for the labels. If you want that it is more difficult and i'd suggest changing your x-axis (so that you dont have to use position = "dodge"

Comment: you're right, it inserts the labels on the middle of high group of bars. How should I change the x-axis? Creating a new one only for the labels?