# r ggplot2 plot two types of bars in addition to colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I need to make a complex barplot and I'd like to have two different variables show up in each of my facetted boxes. Currently I can get the colors

The top 12 rows of my data looks like this:

```
> alldata[1:12,]
            value layer Resolution Season Variable
 1:  1.487185e+01 b.01K        1km   base       ET
 2:  2.280336e+01 b.01K        1km   peak       ET
 3:  3.252913e+01 b.01K        1km summer       ET
 4:  2.379603e+07 b.01K        1km   base        Q
 5:  4.068850e+07 b.01K        1km   peak        Q
 6:  2.265410e+07 b.01K        1km summer        Q
 7: -2.626421e+07 b.01K        1km   base   deltaS
 8:  2.541856e+07 b.01K        1km   peak   deltaS
 9:  2.729352e+06 b.01K        1km summer   deltaS
10:  6.137754e+02 b.01K       100m   base       ET
11:  1.452516e+03 b.01K       100m   peak       ET
12:  2.218111e+03 b.01K       100m summer       ET
```

My code looks like this:

```
melt=melt(alldata,id=c("layer","Resolution","Season","Variable"),measure=c("value"))

print(ggplot(data=melt,aes(x=Season,y=value))
      +geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge",aes(fill=Variable))
      +facet_wrap(~ layer)
)
```

And my plot looks like this (ignore the missing "ET" variable):
[image]

I've got my facets, x-axis groups, and colors how I need, but I cannot find a way to create two different types of bars. For each of my 'id' columns I'd like the following visuals:

```
layer- facet row
scaling factor- facet column
bargroup- season
color- variable
??BARTYPE?? (i.e. one filled and one open, or slashed lines, or anything)- resolution
```

Does anyone know how to create different bartypes (in a line plot I could have dotted lines and regular lines, with the color corresponding to a different variable).

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add texture to fill colors in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alpha`, with some altered data since you didn't share enough:

```
ggplot(data=melt,aes(x=Season,y=value,fill=Variable,alpha=Resolution)) +
   geom_col(position="dodge", col=1)
```

[image]

Add e.g. `scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.4, 1))` to make the lighter bars more solid.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great solution and worked perfectly!