# Superimpose two colors on stacked bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

These are the code and example data for obtaining a stacked barplot with ggplot. Please paste the following example in a text file called "data":

```
Var1 Var2 value
a z 0.17835287
b z 0.20872632
c z 0.54772440
d z 0.04270081
e z 0.02249560
```

and then run in R:

```
if (!require("ggplot2")) {
  install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  library("ggplot2")
}
library("ggplot2")


data = read.delim("data", sep = " ")

ggplot(data[!is.na(data$value),], aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = factor(Var1))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFED00", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#00008F", "#ffffff")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#5AFFA5", "#800000", "#DB0000", "#BE1FC1", "#0047FF")) +
  facet_grid(Var1~., as.table=FALSE, scale="free_y", space = "free_y") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=length(levels(data$Var2)) + 0.5, size=0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1, 0.05),  expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, colour="black", vjust = 1, size=8, hjust=1), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=4),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.line.y=element_line(),
        strip.text.y=element_text(size = 8, colour="black", family="",angle=00, hjust = 0),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.line=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(size = 0.3, colour = "black", linetype = "solid"),
        panel.background=element_blank(), panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.4,0,0.2,0.4), "cm"))
```

You should then see a plot like this one:

[image]

Now I would like to make that some of the stacked bars (a and d) be composed by a background color and another color superimposed on the former, in the shape of stripes, something like the "density" option in the "barplot" function:

```
barplot(c(1), col=c("red"))
barplot(c(1), density=c(2), col=c("blue"), add=T)
```

[image]

To do so, what I was trying was to run twice the "scale_fill_manual" option of ggplot, the first one just filling with colors the a and d bars:

[image]

and then the second one filling all the bars but changing the color of the a and d bars. The problem is that ggplot just overrides the first "scale_fill_manual", and what I would like to do is that the second time the colors of the a and d bars and printed superimposed on the previous, in the shape of stripes. Summing up, the result would be roughly something like this (superimposing the 3rd plot over the 1 plot):

[image]

Do you know any tweak I can do in the "scale_fill_manual" option in order to force this?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, did you get warnings when you ran that? Like "Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing
scale.
Warning message:
`panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead " Also, could you include the code from the failed attempt that you carried out in the last graph?

Comment: Yes, the "Scale for 'fill' is already present" is because I have two consecutive "Scale for 'fill'"s, one producing the 3rd plot and the second producing the first plot, but I would like both of them to superimpose and create the 4th plot

Comment: Thanks, just making sure. The plot you just added looks beautiful you should do it that way ;)

Comment: Thanks! :) I'm on it!

Comment: ggplot2 does not support textured fill.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2) presents a fairly involved hack/workaround to get stripes as fill.