# ggplot2: how to draw bars with two colors in a diagonal pattern

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want one of the bars that I am drawing in ggplot2 to have a diagonal pattern of two colors, similar to this:

[image]

Is that possible? I am currently assigning my colours with this:

```
scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("A" = "forestgreen", 
                                       "B" = "red2", 
                                       "C" = "chocolate1")) +
```

Comment: There is not standard feature in the current ggplot2 that allows you to do this. Any solution will be rather ugly and involved.

Comment: Relevant prior question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2