# Shading lines ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to add shading lines in an area or histogram plot in `ggplot2`?

For example, How could I reproduce the following plot in `ggplot2` ?

```
hist(mtcars$hp, density = 10)
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add texture to fill colors in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Hadley (creator of `ggplot2` package) has stated before that the underlying drawing system [does not support such textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2). Some hack workarounds for this can be found on SO (see alternative answer in suggested dupe), though I haven't tried them myself.

Comment: The solution is a workaround, and I actually wanted to apply it to maps with `geom_sf`. So I'll look for another way to visualize it. Anyway, thank you very much for the help.