# Modify alpha values by group in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change alpha scale, now I think it's from 0 to 1. 
I would like to make it from 0.2 to 0.5 or so..'cause in this way we can't see Event filling colours very well..M"  is too dark and M1 too light..

Here's the database infos:

```
> str(st2)

'data.frame':   24 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Outcome   : Factor w/ 4 levels "LGiT","LGuT",..: 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 ...
 $ Event     : Factor w/ 3 levels "Event 1","Event 2",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Percentage: num  10.31 8.25 81.44 12.77 15.32 ...
 $ Method    : Factor w/ 2 levels "M1","M2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Cohort    : Factor w/ 1 level "Cohort 1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ label     : chr  "10%" "8%" "81%" "13%" ...
 $ sum       : chr  "100.00%" "100.00%" "100.00%" "100.00%" ...
```

Here's the plot code:

```
p7<-ggplot(st2, aes(x = factor(st2$Outcome:st2$Method), y = st2$Percentage,  
                fill = st2$Event, group=st2$Event)) +
  geom_bar(aes(alpha=st2$Method),position = position_stack(), stat = "identity", width = .7, colour="black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = st2$label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size = 4) + coord_flip() 


p8<-p7+labs(x="Outcome", y="Percentage Values", fill="Legend")+ scale_fill_grey(start=1, end=0.8)+ theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=17, face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=13), legend.text=element_text(size=12))


p8+theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Here is my plot:

[image]
I've tried by adding

```
scale_alpha(limits=c(0.2,0.5))
```

but it doesn't work: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.2, 0.5))`

Comment: This works great! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to add a pattern like a dot pattern by method? (M1 with dots and M2 without)

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible with ggplot2 - it just does plain coloured fills. I'm sure somebody has found a way of using textured fills, but I doubt it is straightforward!  I think it is possible in R's base graphics, though.

Comment: Here is an explanation and a heroic attempt to get round it... https://stackoverflow.com/q/2895319/7727429

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I saw this thred but I think it is a bit beyond my capabilities..Is it possible to change borders thickness by method? I'm afraid this plot is not so clear..but I don't know how to make it more explicit..

Comment: Yes, just add a `size` argument to your `geom_bar`, either fixed or as an aesthetic (in which case you might also want a `scale_size_discrete` term)

Comment: I otbain this: Warning message:
Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.

Comment: It is just a warning. You can ignore it as long as the chart is doing what you want.

Comment: ok, thank you! Can I ask something more? Can i reduce the space between 1st and 2nd bars, 3rd and 4th bars etc?

Comment: Not directly. The best way would be to use `Method` as your `x` variable, and to then facet by `Outcome` by adding a term like `+facet_grid(Outcome~.)`

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I hoped there was another way.