# Options for plotting a stacked bar chart in non-colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, textures, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am trying to plot a stacked barchart with 17 different variables (stacked) in a non-colour format.

What are the options for plotting in non-colour such that the differences between the variable stacks are still clear to see?

Comment: Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to post an R question that we can answer. That includes a sample of your data, the code you've written so far, and what hasn't worked yet. I also don't know what "non-color format" means.

Comment: 17 variables is likely too many to show clearly in grayscale, and ggplot does not support textured fill, but if you really want to try textured fill, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1) for some lengthy workarounds to get texture in your ggplot fills. It might be easier to rethink the format of your graph or use a different graphics program though.

Comment: @ Jan Thanks for your comment. It would appear changing to a graded colour format may be more suitable.