# Create stacked bar chart of within group totals

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the dataset below:

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
time = c("1","2"), 
size1=c(200, 300))
```

I add a row to the dataset that is a sum of both time periods:

```
eg_data <- rbind(eg_data, (data.frame(time="1 + 2", 
size1=sum(eg_data$size1))))
eg_data$time <- factor(eg_data$time, levels = c("1 + 2", "1", "2"))
```

I create a bar graph

```
eg_data_bar <- (ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=eg_data, aes(y = size1, x = time, fill = time), 
stat="identity",position='stack'))

eg_data_bar
```

As it stands now, the graph renders out as three bars which are different colors. I need the bar chart to render as three bars, period 1 is one color, period 2 is another color, and the grouped period 1 + 2 is made up of the two colors from period 1 and period 2.

The problem I'm having is how to define fill within the geom_bar(). When I've done stacked bars before, I always have a third column to use as the fill.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"and the grouped period 1 + 2 is made up of the two colors from period 1 and period 2"* I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by that? Are you after some form of pattern fill, showing two colours for the *same* bar? As far as I know that will be impossible ([difficult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2)) in `ggplot2`.

Comment: I need the final output to be three bars...period 1, period 2, and period 1 + 2. I need period 1 to be...red, period 2 to be...blue, and period 1 + 2 to period 1 and period 2, stacked on top of each other, so you can see the relationship b/t p1 totals, p2 totals, and how p1 and p2 look as proportions of the overall total. In a single visual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

We start from your initial `eg_data` `data.frame`:

```
eg_data <- data.frame(
    time = c("1","2"),
    size1 = c(200, 300))


library(tidyverse)
eg_data %>%
    mutate(grp = factor(time, levels = 1:2)) %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    complete(grp) %>%
    replace_na(list(size1 = 0)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    spread(time, size1) %>%
    mutate(`1+2` = `1` + `2`) %>%
    gather(time, size, -grp) %>%
    mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("1", "2", "1+2"))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(time, size, fill = grp)) +
    geom_col(position = "stack")
```

[image]

The key is to add an additional `grp` variable which we use to `fill` the bars.

Solution below is solution above, it adds grp to the dataframe and creates the graph as its own object, so it can be called ad-hoc.

```
eg_data <- eg_data %>% 
mutate(grp = factor(time, levels = 1:2)) %>%
group_by(time) %>%
complete(grp) %>%
replace_na(list(size1 = 0)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
spread(time, size1) %>%
mutate(`1+2` = `1` + `2`) %>%
gather(time, size1, -grp) %>%
mutate(time = factor(time, levels = c("1", "2", "1+2")))

eg_data_graph <-  (ggplot(data = eg_data, aes(time, size1, fill = grp)) +
geom_col(position = "stack"))

eg_data_graph
```

Comment: I am not as familiar w tidyverse, so some of the commands are foreign to me, but this does exactly what I need. Thank you!!!