# ggplot2: Add Different Textures to Colored Barplot and Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, textures, bar-chart, legend

Based on the ggplot2 package, I want to add different textures to different bars of a barplot. Furthermore, I want to add these textures to the legend of the barplot.

Consider the following reproducible example:

```
# Create example data
data_ggp <- data.frame(category = rep(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3"), 4),
                       values = c(0.664, 0.045, 0.291, 0.482, 0.029, 0.489, 0.537, 0.027, 0.436, 0.536, 0.028, 0.436),
                       group = c(rep("group1a", 3), rep("group1b", 3), rep("group2a", 3), rep("group2b", 3)))

# Load ggplot2
library("ggplot2")

# Draw barchart (not overlayed)
ggplot(data_ggp, aes(category, values)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = group), position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(" ", 
                    labels = c("group1a", "group1b", "group2a", "group2b"),
                    values = c("group1a" = "deepskyblue4", "group1b" = "darkolivegreen4", 
                               "group2a" = "deepskyblue1", "group2b" = "darkolivegreen2"))
```

[image]

To this barplot, I would like to draw diagonal lines to group 2a and vertical + horizontal lines to group 2b. The legend should contain these textures, too.

The final barplot should look as follows (drawn in paint):

[image]

I found a relatively old thread on stack overflow: [How to add texture to fill colors in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2/20426482#20426482)

Unfortunately, this code is very complex, not automatized, and difficult to apply to different types of barplots. Furthermore, I would like to add the textures to my legend.

**Question: How to add different textures to different bars of a barplot + to the legend of the barplot?**

Comment: Check Hadley's answer in the linked post. It appears there's no update yet. Therefore, your best bet is on that function however complex it is. Perhaps try to refactor it?

Comment: Maybe this? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patternplot/patternplot.pdf

Comment: @NelsonGon Have you seen that I am mentioning this thread in my question? The other thread has a very unautomized code and it also is not showing how to add texture to a legend. The answer of Check Hadley is from 2010, so there might have been an update since then.

Comment: Check my comment on Hadley's answer? That was last year. There's no update. I thought of this myself late last year.

Comment: I saw your comment from last year, but since he didn't reply I am still wondering if there might be an update. Thank you for the link to the package, did you have success with the package?

Comment: Running the examples in the package produces some textured bars.

Comment: @IanCampbell Thank you so much for showing me this. In fact, I was so impressed by the ggpattern package that I have created a tutorial about the package on my website. In case you are interested, you may check it out here: https://statisticsglobe.com/ggpattern-r-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [ggpattern](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2020/04/01/introducing-ggpattern-pattern-fills-for-ggplot/)

```r
# remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)

data_ggp <- data.frame(category = rep(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3"), 4),
                       values = c(0.664, 0.045, 0.291, 0.482, 0.029, 0.489, 0.537, 0.027, 0.436, 0.536, 0.028, 0.436),
                       group = c(rep("group1a", 3), rep("group1b", 3), rep("group2a", 3), rep("group2b", 3)))

ggplot(data_ggp, aes(category, values)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", 
                   pattern = c("none", "none", "none", # 1st col
                               "none", "none", "none", # 2nd col
                               "stripe", "stripe", "stripe", # 3rd col
                               "crosshatch", "crosshatch", "crosshatch" # 4th col 
                               ),
                   pattern_angle = c(rep(0, 6), rep(45, 3), rep(0, 3)),
                   pattern_density = .1,
                   pattern_spacing = .04,
                   pattern_fill = 'black',
                   aes(fill = group), 
                   position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(" ", 
                    labels = c("group1a", "group1b", "group2a", "group2b"),
                    values = c("group1a" = "deepskyblue4", "group1b" = "darkolivegreen4", 
                               "group2a" = "deepskyblue1", "group2b" = "darkolivegreen2")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                               list(
                                 pattern = c("none", "none", "stripe", "crosshatch"),
                                 pattern_spacing = .01,
                                 pattern_angle = c(0, 0, 45, 0)
                                 )
                             ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>