# How to position overlapping bar plot and bar width manually?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to generate 3 overlapping bar plots that looks like the plot below:

[image]

but couldn't find an easy way on how to do this.

Here is what I have tried:

```
d1 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.8)
d2 <- c(0.15, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 3.3)
d3 <- c(0.16,0.7,0.7,1,2.5)

barplot(d1, # calling data
        ylim = c(0,5), # set y-limit
        width = c(1,1,1,1,1), # change barwidth,
        space = 0.2,
        col = yarrr::transparent("gray", trans.val = 0.9)) # change bar colour and transparency

par(new=T) # allow second chart to overlay the previous chart. Alternatively can use add=TRUE, e.g. barplot(df,add=TRUE)

barplot(d2, ylim=c(0,5), width = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), 
        space=c(0.4,rep(1.4,4)),
        density = c(5,5), angle=c(45,45), # assign angle and density of lines within bar
        axes=F)

par(new=T)

barplot(d3, ylim=c(0,5), width = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), 
        space= 10,
        density = c(15,15,15), angle=c(0,0,0), # assign angle and density of lines within bar
        axes=F)
```

And this is the closest I can achieve:

[image]
The first problem I'm facing is that the width of the first bar plot doesn't change even I've assigned different width (width =1) from those in the second (width=0.5) and third plot (width=0.5).

The second problem is that I couldn't find a simple way to position the 2nd and 3rd plot within the 1st plot properly. I want the 2nd and 3rd bar plots side by side within the 1st bar plot and that their total width equals the width of the first bar plot.

Can someone help please? I'm accepting ggplot solution also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```r
d1 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.8)
d2 <- c(0.15, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 3.3)
d3 <- c(0.16,0.7,0.7,1,2.5)

df <- data.frame(d1, d2, d3)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(index = seq_along(d1)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = index, y = d1),
    width = 0.8,
    col = "black",
    fill = "forestgreen"
  ) +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = index, y = d2),
    width = 0.4,
    col = "black",
    fill = "red",
    position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = 0.2)
  ) +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = index, y = d3),
    width = 0.4,
    col = "black",
    fill = "blue",
    position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = -0.2)
  ) +
  labs(y = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Update: patterns instead of colors

This is actually not straightforward with ggplot2 itself. If you're OK with downloading packages outside CRAN then you can download [`ggpattern`](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/index.html) and do something like this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(index = seq_along(d1)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    aes(x = index, y = d1),
    width = 0.8,
    col = "black",
    fill = "forestgreen"
  ) +
  ggpattern::geom_col_pattern(
    aes(x = index, y = d2),
    width = 0.4,
    color = "black",
    fill = "white",
    pattern = 'stripe',
    pattern_size = 0.1,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = 0.2)
  ) +
  ggpattern::geom_col_pattern(
    aes(x = index, y = d3),
    width = 0.4,
    color = "black",
    fill = "lightgray",
    pattern = 'crosshatch',
    pattern_fill = "black",
    pattern_angle = 0,
    pattern_size = 0.1,
    position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = -0.2)
  ) +
  labs(y = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`ggpattern` is well [documented](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/index.html), so you should be able to adjust the above example to your needs.

If you don't want to rely on packages outside CRAN then you can take a look at any of these old questions for possible workarounds:

- [How to add texture to fill colors in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Adding hatches or patterns to ggplot bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164758/adding-hatches-or-patterns-to-ggplot-bars?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [ggplot2: Add Different Textures to Colored Barplot and Legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093283/ggplot2-add-different-textures-to-colored-barplot-and-legend?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can I add hatches, stripes or another pattern or texture to a barplot in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp)

Comment: Thanks @jpiversen. You're the champ. Btw, can you also show how to add different textures, e.g. stripes for bar plot 2 and 3, no fill colour,  instead of blue and red? Bar plot 1 can remain forestgreen.

And where can I find more info, i.e. documentation on how these work? to learn more?

Comment: I don't have any specific sources for the overlapping columns, but I have some general ones. If you're new to ggplot, then [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) is a good primer. If you want to know everything there is to know, you can read Hadley's [book on ggplot](https://ggplot2-book.org/). Also the [package documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) has many nice articles. And of course, google is your friend.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution to the textures.

Comment: Thanks @jpiversen! I've tried ggpattern and did pretty much everything you had except ggpattern::geom_col_pattern. I wrote geom_col_pattern instead lol. Btw, may I ask what's your expertise?

Answer (score 0):

I see like a back and a front layer of each two bars. To obtain this, the combination of the width and the nudging is crucial, I believe this should do the job:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


group_var <- 1:5
d1 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.8)
d2 <- c(0.15, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 3.3)
d3 <- c(0.16,0.7,0.7,1,2.5)
d4 <- c(1.162,0.7,0.7,1,3.5)

df <- data.frame(group_var, d1, d2, d3, d4)

p <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = group_var, y = d1), width = 0.4, col = "black", 
           fill = "grey", position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = 0.2)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = group_var, y = d4), width = 0.4, col = "black", 
           fill = "black", position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = -0.2)  ) +
  geom_col(aes(x = group_var, y = d2), width = 0.2, col = "black", 
           fill = "red",    position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = 0.1)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = group_var, y = d3), width = 0.2, col = "black",
           fill = "blue",   position = ggplot2::position_nudge(x = -0.3))
print(p)
```