# Two different colour/pattern schemes for boxplots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to colour my plot to be the image below with a colour scheme across Transect locations but also between the two different Communities: All species and Without *Clidemia hirta*.

I would like a pattern for one of the communities, but I can't figure out a way to do this in ggplot2 (the image below was manipulated after exporting). I have managed to apply an alpha colour to differentiate the two communities, and although this looked good on the graph, you could not see a difference between the two in the legend.

Plot I want to achieve

[image: Plot I want to achieve:]

My data:

```
    Transect.location = c("Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest less disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest less disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest less disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest less disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest less disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest less disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest disturbed", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Oil palm", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Oil palm", "Oil palm", "Forest disturbed", "Oil palm", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest disturbed")
    woodiness = c(1, 0.605128205, 1, 0.230538922, 1, 0.891891892, 1, 0.169014085, 1, 0.417624521, 1, 0.234513274, 1, 0.317073171, 1, 0.597484277, 0.695238095, 0.236151603, 0.064516129, 1, 0.667655786, 1, 0.285714286, 1, 0.96, 1, 0.974025974, 0.732142857, 0.293929712, 1, 0.346153846, 0.127659574, 0.613793103, 0.2265625, 0.210045662, 0.025, 0.196581197, 0.254385965, 0, 0.05952381, 0.330434783, 0.051660517, 0.056179775, 0.126760563, 1, 0.571428571, 0, 0, 0.126213592, 0.116666667, 0.015384615, 0.53968254, 0.733333333, 0.417085427, 0.092307692, 0.041666667, 0.482758621, 0.018181818, 0.169172932, 0)
    Community = c("All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "All species", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta", "Without Clidemia hirta")

    data = data.frame(Transect.location, woodiness, Community)
    data$Transect.location<-factor(data$Transect.location, levels=c("Oil palm", "Forest-oil palm edge", "Forest disturbed", "Forest less disturbed"))
```

My code:

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Transect.location, y = woodiness, alpha = factor(Community), fill = factor(Transect.location))) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Transect.location))+
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Transect.location", values = c("#FDECCD", "#BAE4B3", "#329A55", "#075507"))+
    scale_alpha_manual(name = "Community", values = c(1, 0.5))
```

Comment: Patterns are difficult in ggplot. But how about using the colour aesthetic to differentiate the two communities. Alternatively facet by community or transect location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do this within native `ggplot`.

You can somewhat hack it if you really, really want patterns (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2/20426482#20426482)).

You can also play with the `linetype`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Transect.location, y = woodiness, linetype = factor(Community), fill = factor(Transect.location))) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Transect.location))+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Transect.location", values = c("#FDECCD", "#BAE4B3", "#329A55", "#075507"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(name = "Community", values = c(1, 0.5)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Community", values = c("solid", "dotted"))
```

[image]

Or `facet_grid`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Transect.location, y = woodiness, fill = factor(Transect.location))) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Transect.location))+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Transect.location", values = c("#FDECCD", "#BAE4B3", "#329A55", "#075507"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(name = "Community", values = c(1, 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(~Community)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arienrhod, that's what I thought might be the case! But you've suggested two good options that solve the legend issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

This should work, the code for your plot was good but it just needed a little tweaking to include code for the pattern. So I included a line with `geom_boxplot_pattern` and removed your `scale_alpha_manual`

I replaced `alpha = factor(Community)` with `pattern = Community`

Boxplot with pattern code:

```
library(ggplot2)
remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)

    myplot <-
ggplot(data, aes(x = Transect.location, y = woodiness, pattern = Community, fill = Transect.location)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Transect.location))+
scale_fill_manual(name = "Transect.location", values = c("#FDECCD", "#BAE4B3", "#329A55", "#075507")) +
geom_boxplot_pattern(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), color = "black", pattern_fill = "white", pattern_angle = 45, pattern_density = 0.1, pattern_spacing = 0.025, pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")), fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))

myplot
```

[Here is the picture of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZhD.jpg)

If you also want to specify a pattern just for "Without Clidemia hirta" you need to include a line with `scale_pattern_manual` but I'm sorry I couldn't get this to work. It might be due to the spaces in the name "Without Clidemia hirta" but it would be something like this:

```
    scale_pattern_manual(values = c(All_species = "stripe", Without_Clidemia_hirta = "none"))
```

I really hope this helps, I've struggled to find boxplots with manual patterns and manual colours to easily copy + paste so I hope this fulfils that purpose for others in my old position!