# ggplot red-white gradient appears orange

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, gradient, heatmap

I've created a heat map in ggplot and I'm using a default red to white `scale_fill_gradient`. When I plot the gradient however, it appears to have an orange tint. I was wondering if there was a way to edit how `ggplot` calculates the gradient so that I get pink intermediates so that it matches the other figures I'm making. Related to this graph, though I can post separately, I want to make my NA values have a striped pattern (rather than grey fill). I haven't found a way to do that in `ggplot`.

```
    p <- ggplot(heat.data, aes(x = MutResFac, y = mutAA, fill = disruption)) +
            geom_tile(color="grey50") +
            scale_fill_gradient(name = "Disruption", limits = c(0,3),
                                 labels = c("WT-like", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"),
                                 low = "#FFFFFF", high = "#FF0000",
                                 guide = "legend") +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25, hjust = 1), 
                  text = element_text(size = 25), 
                  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
            coord_fixed() +
            labs(x = "Position", y = "Mutant Amino Acid") +
            ggtitle(title) + 
            scale_x_discrete(labels = wildTypeSeqLabels)
```

[image: A example plot of the data]

Comment: Are you having the night light mode enabled on your screen?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer as to why your middle range of colors from red to white comes out orange is that he in-between color value from `#FF0000` and white is orange.  The better practical color theory answer is that `#FF0000` is a yellowish or orange-ish red, and not a blueish red, so the middle color will be orangeish.  The most technical answer is [explained in the technical documentation for the gradient color scale functions](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html).  The `scale_..._gradient` functions create the gradient based on keeping hue constant and varying chroma and luminance.

#### Options to fix scale

For this, I'll use an example dataset and plot with the base code here:

```
set.seed(1111)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10,1,0.2), values=1:10)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill=values)) + geom_col(width=0.7)
```

You can consider one of the following:

1. select a more blue-ish red to start with:

   p + scale_fill_gradient(low='#FFFFFF', high='#FE43AF')

[image]

2. Select your scale more discretely using `scale_fill_gradientn`:

   pal <- c('#F8F6F6', '#F4AABC', '#E83D7D')
   p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal)

[image]

Incidentally, the function `choose_color()` from the `colorspace` package is a pretty useful little tool (requires `shiny` and `shinyjs` to be installed, as it's a shiny app) that can be helpful for choosing colors.  [This guide](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) may also come in handy.  `scale_fill_gradientn` and use of the `choose_color()` to set your palette gives you complete control, but it has a tendency to make the transition kind of odd: this is why I like the first gradient shown above vs. the second.

#### Patterned fills

Currently, there are no good, simple methods to create patterned fill in `ggplot` to my knowledge.  Could be useful to ask a question, but [the best seems to be this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2).  Not really too satisfactory, IMO, but it seems at the moment to be the best that can be done.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining how the gradient was calculated! If I want to use a gradient that is calculated on the rgb scale, it looks like I might have to make my own color palette.