# How to draw a Two-group Histogram with split longitudinally bars in the overlaying part with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, visualization, overlap

I want the overlapping part of a histogram to show the bar divided by a diagonal line, for example, I created the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
grupo1 <- round(rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 2.2))
grupo2 <- round(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2))

df <- data.frame(
  valores = c(grupo1, grupo2),
  grupo = c(rep("grupo1", length(grupo1)), rep("grupo2", length(grupo2)))
)

# Crear histograma
ggplot(df, aes(x = valores, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, color = "black", position = "identity", alpha=0.6) +
  labs(x = "Valores", y = "Frecuencia", fill = "Grupo") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grupo1" = "blue", "grupo2" = "red")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

This code results in this plot:
[result, note that the part that overlaps is a different color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzIXB.png)

But I want the plot to be drawn like this (I modified it in paint):
[what I want, note that shows both colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Uc4.png)
Does anyone know how to draw the histogram as the last image shows?

A second example, following the same code:

```
    df2 <- rbind(df, data.frame(valores = c(15,15), grupo = c("grupo1", "grupo1")))
```

This is the result:
[2° example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjtgF.png)
But i want this (modified in paint):
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wvDU.png)

I have tried some 'geom_histogram' arguments such as changing the 'position' but does not work
I expect a code that solves my issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: In your example both groups have the same frequency (1) for valores = 15, so the column should have height 1. But what if it weren't the case? If grupo1 had 3 observations with valores = 15, and grupo2 had only 1, what would be the size of the column?

Comment: Hello @RicardoSemiãoeCastro, I have added two observations to grupo 1 with valores =15, with the following code:
valores<-c(15,15)
grupo<-c("grupo1", "grupo1")
add3<-cbind(valores, grupo)
df2<-rbind(df, add3)
str(df2)
df2$valores <- as.numeric(df2$valores)
The same plot shows a column of height 3 in valores=15, the lower part (the first third) of that column is "purple", as in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzIXB.png and the second and third parts are blue.
Hope i made myself understood

Comment: Ok, I got it, but now, in that new case (with `df2`), how would the graph with the diagonally splitted bar look? Because the "blue" part of the bar should have height = 3, whereas the red should have height = 1. So how do you want to combine these two bars into a single, diagonally splitted, bar? Maybe edit your question with this new dataframe and create a new image of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already edited the question.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. I believe that it's very similar to what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ggplot2 doesn't work well with this kind of thing. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2) is about adding textures to bar plots, something similar to what you want, and it comes at great difficulty.

I've come up with some really weird solutions, there might be a way easier approach that I don't know.

Obs: dummy data (`df2`) at the end.

### Option 1 - bars with combined colors, but not combined heights

This is basically what you said you didn't wanted, but with an improvement: the combined bar doesn't have the sum of the heights. See, if we made:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(valores, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, color = "black", alpha=0.6)
```

The bar at `valores = 15` will have `count = 3 + 1`, but we might prefer a `count = 3` bar with another samller `count = 1` bar below. We can get that using `position_dodge()`, but requesting no actual dodge:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(valores, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_histogram(position = position_dodge(0), binwidth = 1, color = "black", alpha=0.6)
```

[image]

But we can also add a small amount of dogdge. Using `position_dodge(0.3)`:

[image]

The problem with this solution is that it adds whitespace between the bars. There might be an option to `geom_histogram` that removes it, but I don't know. You can open a new question if you'd like to.

### Option 2 - faking bars using `geom_area` + `geom_segment`

You can build a new dataset with the values of the histogram, then you get more flexibility to customize the bars. You could do that with `hist()`, but since we're using ggplot, I made individual histograms for each group, and got their data with `ggplot_build()`. There might be a better way to do that, the important part is that at the end you have a dataset with the histogram values for each group.

```
df_area <- df2 %>%
  group_split(grupo) %>% #for each group
  map_dfr(function(df_group){ #apply the following function
    g <- ggplot(df_group, aes(valores)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) #build a histogram
    
    ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]] %>% #get it's data
      select(c(x, xmin, xmax, y)) %>% #select these columns
      mutate(grupo = unique(df_group$grupo)) %>% #and add a 'grupo' column
      pivot_longer(c(xmin, xmax), values_to = "x_area") #pivot the data in order to build columns with geom_area
  })
```

Now, we can build the area of the histogram with `geom_area`, and the lines with `geom_segment`. Again we use `position_dodge(0)`, but this time, no whitespace!:

```
ggplot(df_area, aes(x_area, y, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(0), alpha = 0.6, color = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = y, x = x_area, xend = x_area))
```

[image]

This might yield these weird boundaries between the area contour and the segments. Also, can't use `position_dodge(k)` with `k != 0`.

### Option 3 - `geom_area` + `geom_segment` with custom data

This is the closest to what you wanted. The ideia is to change the data:

```
df_area2 <- df_area %>%
  mutate(y = case_when(grupo == "grupo1" ~ ifelse(name == "xmin", y, 0),
                       grupo == "grupo2" ~ ifelse(name == "xmax", y, 0)))
```

In such a way to produce the inclined bars:

[image]

Then, we add that on top of the base graph of the last image:

```
ggplot(df_area, aes(x_area, y, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(0), color = "black") +
  geom_area(data = df_area2) + #on top of the base area, but below the lines
  geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = y, x = x_area, xend = x_area))
```

[image]

Using `alpha` here will make the inclined bars visible. You can pass "washed out" colors to `fill` in order to match the previous tone you had.

Lastly, we can add lines at the end of the half bars:

```
binwidth <- 1

ggplot(df_area, aes(x_area, y, fill = grupo)) +
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(0), color = "black") +
  geom_area(data = df_area2) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = y, x = x_area, xend = x_area)) +
  geom_segment(aes(y = y, yend = y, x = x - 0.5*binwidth, xend = x + 0.5*binwidth))
```

Here, `binwidth` is the same one you used to create the histogram data.

[image]

### Dummy data

```
set.seed(1)
grupo1 <- round(rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 2.2))
grupo2 <- round(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2))

df <- data.frame(valores = c(grupo1, grupo2),
                 grupo = c(rep("grupo1", length(grupo1)), rep("grupo2", length(grupo2))))

df2 <- rbind(df, data.frame(valores = c(15,15), grupo = c("grupo1", "grupo1")))
```